# Database has been placed in a state by user 'XXX' on machine 'XXX'

Tags: ms-access

I implemented a system in which I can monitor which users are using which databases from which computer, and also I'm able to click a checkbox in the back-end to  kick them off. The problem is that some of my users are getting a runtime error 3734 once in a while in their front-end database.

The way I'm making this work is with a hidden form that opens when the user opens the front-end and closes when the user closes the program. When it opens, it writes into the database the user's name, computer, time they logged in and the program they're using. And when the close the program it just deletes the log from that specific user and program. As for the kick off method, I'm running a timer in that hidden form that checks every 5 seconds if the checkmark for a user is on or off, if it's on, the program closes.

This is the code that appears in the debugger when the error 3734 appears:

```
Private Sub Form_Timer()
    If DLookup("[Kick]", "[Log]", "[DbName] = 'Grupos & Agentes' And [User] = '" & fOSUserName() & "'") = -1 Then
        Application.Quit
    End If
End Sub
```

Is the problem the timer or am I missing something?

Comment: First, try taking the error description at face value. From the details, I assume that the table `[Kick]` is in the back end.  Apparently another user has opened the backend database in a state that disallows other connections.  Perhaps someone is opening the backend directly in Access, or the problem could be with other code in your front-end that is locking the database.  How are you "linking" to the backend? Basic linked tables, or ADODB connections, other techniques?  Also, the short code snippet has an unknown (to anyone viewing here) function `fOSUserName()` which could have problems.

Comment: At the least, you could add error handling code (ALWAYS a good idea) that adds a short delay and tries again.  Perhaps the locking is short-lived and you could tolerate an extra second delay in trying again.